# Curl an API inside the same container on a container start

Tags: docker, curl

I'm trying to execute curl to add a value to the API within the same container where API is starting.

Dockerfile command which I'm using to get that to work looks like

```
CMD java -jar ./my-api.jar ; wait 30; curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/user/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "username: "admin", "data": {"email": "admin@test.com", "password" : "somepassword"}}'
```

but the admin used was not added after 30 seconds when API got started.

The same curl command works fine when I will execute it within the container itself.

Any thought on that?

Comment: Dockerfile and run command?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer `RUN` will execute it during the build time

Comment: Instead of making an HTTP request, can you change your application's `main()` function to do the required setup itself?  (How would you do this task if Docker weren't involved?)

Comment: @DavidMaze code change cannot be taken into account. When docker is not involved then I will use UI or DB update but I need to have that user set before other container will start.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved with moving all to the scrip and then execute it with the `CMD`

Script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
java -java -jar ./my-api.jar  &
sleep 20
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/user/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "username: "admin", "data": {"email": "admin@test.com", "password" : "somepassword"}}'
fg %1
```